# Fire deferred change event when text field input changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

According to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Is there a way to make the text fields and text areas fire an event when the input text is changed and not only when they lose focus?

Comment: You're looking for the html5 `input` event

Comment: Perfect. Make this an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the html5 [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input):

```
$(…).on("input", function(e) {…});
```

However, it doesn't work in older browsers. You can hook on multiple events (most relevant `keyup`), and fire your listener on each of them. If you're doing rather heavy computations, you should filter to those events only that led to an actual change:

```
var val;
$(…).on("input change keyup keypress cut paste mouseup focus blur", function(e) {
    if (this.value !== val)
        val = this.value;
        …
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

using keyup like this

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

```
$( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for input that isn't via the keyboard e.g paste, drag and drop.