# Laravel PHP Jquery - TextBox updating Label

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have this textbox

```
{{ Form::text('horasT', $horasT, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'0.00')) }}
```

I want to update a Label when the textbox value changes.

this is the label:

```
<label id="subTotal" name="subTotal">0</label>
```

My Jquery is this:

```
jQuery('#horasT').on('input', function (){
            var valT = $('#horasT').val();
            $('#subTotal').value = valT;
        });
```

It doesn't seem to work and I've tried a lot of things so far.

But for me this should work... What seems to be the problem? The label just sits in 0 no matter the value that is in the textbox

Comment: Add in the array `'id' => 'horasT'`. I am not sure if `Form::text` would automatically give an ID. I remeber some of its methods (Form) were adding it while others don't.

Comment: Tip : When you don't know if an event is triggered or not, just add an alert in your code to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event is `change` and a label has text not value

Possible other event to trigger on: `"input change keyup keypress cut paste mouseup focus blur"`

```js
jQuery(document).on('change', '#horasT', function (){
            var valT = $(this).val();
            $('[name="subTotal"]').text(valT);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="horasT" name="subTotal">0</label>
<input id="horasT" type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been struggling with this.

Comment: If you want it to change as you are typing and not only on losing focus you may want to change `on('change',...` to `on('change input',...` [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22748097/428543)

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery("#horasT").change(function() {
    $("#subTotal").text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Please try to provide some explanation and/or relevant links to explain *why* your code should work. Code-only answers are typically low quality answers.